# Выровнять текст по центру (по вертикали) у div с display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, текст

Выровнять текст по центру (по вертикали) у `div` с `display: inline-block`. При использовании `vertical-align` меняется положение самого блока. Возможно ли это сделать без обертывания текста в `<p>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  text-align: center;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможно

Мой любимый костыль, сам пользуюсь

```
<style>
.div-table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.div-table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

В любой нужный элемент вписывается div-table, в него div-table-cell, и вот в него уже всё, что нужно разместить по центру по вертикали

```
<div>
   <div class="div-table">
      <div class="div-table-cell">
         ...что угодно, не только текст
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Не самый лучший вариант тк тут меняется тип элемента.

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align:

> Оно применяется только к строчным элементам inline или строчным блокам
>   inline-block.   Оно влияет на выравнивание самого элемента, а не его
>   содержимого (кроме случаев, когда применяется к ячейкам таблицы).
>   Когда оно применяется к ячейке таблицы, выравнивание влияет на
>   содержимое ячейки, а не на неё саму.